# How to show countdown on windows form after the media end

Tags: c#

I am using a listBox to play media files with the axWindowsMediaPlayer on form in which the next media plays after a time gap for which I have used a timer.Now I want to display a coundown timer on screen for that time gap.How to do this..plz help.The code how I am using the timer at media end is:

```
   System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    object _locker = new object();
     Player.PlayStateChange += Player_PlayStateChange;

        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Interval = 3000;
    void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        _timer.Stop();
        lock (_locker)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            if (listBox2.SelectedIndex + 1 < listBox2.Items.Count)
            {

                listBox2.SelectedItem = listBox2.Items[listBox2.SelectedIndex + 1];
            }
        });
        }
    }

    void Player_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
    {
        if ((WMPLib.WMPPlayState)e.newState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded)
        {
               _timer.Start();


        }
        else if ((WMPLib.WMPPlayState)e.newState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsReady)
        {

                Player.Ctlcontrols.play();


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put in _timer_Elapsed() a counter

```
private int m_counter=0;
```

make it 0 each for media(lets say after media has started)

and create a Label to show the counter.ToString()

Comment: I tried using a new timer with same time interval as in _timer_Elapsed and it was working but I was unable to reset the timer after second media starts

Comment: add Event of media start(don't know the name of the event), in the event reset this timer and make the countTimer enable False.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private  int totalwaittime = 5;
    private  int counter = 0;
    private static void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
    {
        counter++;
        Label1.text = String.Format("Time Left : {0}", totalwaittime - counter);
        if (totalwaittime - counter == 0)
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
            //play next file
        }
    }

    void Player_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
    {
        if ((WMPLib.WMPPlayState)e.newState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded)
        {
            counter = 0;
            timer.Enabled = true;


        }
        else if ((WMPLib.WMPPlayState)e.newState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsReady)
        {

            Player.Ctlcontrols.play();


        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to display a countdown timer after each media ends and when the counter comes to 0 the other media should play and counter should reset.